# Why can't docker container connect to database from environment variables?

Tags: docker

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
    
WORKDIR /app
    
COPY package*.json ./
    
RUN npm install —force
    
COPY . .
    
ENV NODE_ENV=production
    
EXPOSE 3000
    
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

and here is the .env file with database configuration and private key for JWT:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_DATABASE=chat

SECRET_KEY='qwerty'
```

Why can't the Docker container connect to the database?
I'm trying to run `docker run -p 3000:3000`

Comment: No error messages to report?

Comment: Error that just trying to connect to the database, I can send text. The container is started using `docker run -p 3000:3000`

Comment: Each container is its own `localhost`, so `DB_HOST=localhost` tells the application container to connect to the application container.  If the database is also in a container, both containers need to be on the same `docker run --network`.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a `.env` file, it will not be read automatically by `docker`. You need to pass the `--env-file` option:

```
$ docker run -p 3000:3000 --env-file .env <your image>
```

Comment: I don't know why but still no database connection